# Exponential Distribution Properties

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have the question: What property of the exponential distribution is guaranteed when we assume that $\lambda$ has the form of $\exp(−X\beta)$ ?

I am assuming it is the memoryless property but I don't know the reason why it is or what the memoryless property means.

Comment: Have you read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness?

Comment: If $X$ and $\beta$ are real numbers then $\exp(−X\beta)$ is a positive number.  If $X$ and $\beta$ are positive numbers then $\exp(−X\beta) <1$, so if $\lambda$ is the rate then the expectation would be below $1$.  I am not sure there is much more to say